# Does anyone know why i cannot see the source code of a website while in Internet Explorer mode in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, internet-explorer-9

I need to see the source code on a website that only works in Internet Explorer mode in Microsoft Edge. Whereas on Micrososft Edge you can see the source code by by pressing shift + ctrl + c, when I try doing that on Internet Explorer the source code is empty.

If I right click on the website in Internet Explorer and press "show source" I get this weird html script on Notepad instead of the popup interface. Can anyone help? Thank You!

Comment: May I know if you have checked my answer? If there's any question, you can share with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that pressing `shift + ctrl + c` calls out Edge Developer Tools, which only works in Microsoft Edge, not in Internet Explorer mode. That's why it won't show anything. Also, it is by design that right-clicking and then selecting View Source launches Notepad.

To view source code of IE mode pages, you should use a standalone developer tools for IE mode called **IEChooser**

1. In Windows, open the Run dialog. For example, press `Windows logo key + R`.
2. Enter **%systemroot%\system32\f12\IEChooser.exe**, and then click OK.
3. In IEChooser, select the entry for the IE mode tab.

Article for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/ie-mode/